# Magento Sales > export to csv permissions

Tags: magento, permissions

Im working on a magento webshop and want to make an export of the shipments.

These shipments can be exported via sales > export to csv. However, I'm not able to access this section of the store:

[image]

I can access this page as admin with full permissions ( set with system > permissions > roles ), but when i choose custom rights instead of all rights the page goes blank again.

It also goes blank after i choose custom rights and select all the options.

We recently updated patch 6788 and 7405, so it is possible that it's something with these patches.

Hopefully someone can help me fast.

Thanks in advance ;)

EDIT:
I made a new role with a custom recourse access and checked all checkboxes (so I expect this will give full admin rights). After this I added a new user with this new role assigned. Still having the access denied page for sales > export to csv > export shipments.
[image]

If i set the role resource access to all i'm able to access the specific page. Still having no clue why i can't access the page with custom resource access.

SECOND EDIT:
I searched for a checkbox about exporting to a csv and found the options. However, they were checked. Still having the problems. 
[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be that the new patch changed some of the roles. Change the permissions for a roles under `System>Permissions>Roles`. After your role is set up, give it to a user under `System>Permissions>Users`.

Comment: @zack-l Thanks for your help. I have edited my question with your possible solution. Still having the same problems

Comment: Hmm, is this a custom extension? Also, is there a checkbox nested under sales for export to csv? If its a custom extension the permissions code may have an error. I have encountered this before.

Comment: No, this is the standard permissions part of magento. Problems happened after updating to patch 6788 and 7405 right after it. I also can't find a nested checkbox under sales export. The checkboxes that I found were about exporting to a csv were checked (see edit on post)